# Where is text in element coming from?

Tags: html, css

I was messing around with some buttons online and came by a button that displays an arrow when hovered over.

I'm looking through the css and the html for this element but can't see this arrow they're displaying anywhere.

The button is an `a` tag with a span inside, like this:

```
 <a href="#" id="makeGroupButton">
    <span>Button</span>
 </a>
```

When a user hovers over it some text gets appended to it somehow, but I can't figure out how that's happening.

I made a JsFiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/aoprjmxr/

The css is beyond my scope, can anybody help me see where this arrow is getting inserted?

Answer (score 1):

using `:after` and `:before` http://jsfiddle.net/aoprjmxr/1/

```
#makeGroupButton:hover:before {
  content: 'before';
  display: inline-block;
}

#makeGroupButton:hover:after {
  content: 'after';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

like so you can also show `background-image: url(path/to/image)` and you can also set position and so on

Comment: @MarksCode does this answer your question or you still searching for the right answer? Also in chrome browser you can debug and mark `hover` for all elements and then you will also find the `:after` and `:before` elements

Answer (score 0):

```
#makeGroupButton span:after 
{
  content: '';  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -14px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
}

#makeGroupButton:hover span, #makeGroupButton:active span 
{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#makeGroupButton:hover span:after, #makeGroupButton:active span:after 
{
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: white;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

This CSS is doing the magic!

Answer (score 0):

Made it with `#makeGroupButton span:after` and add `right: -14px;` By default,
when you hover it, then : `right: 0;` and you can see the `span`

Answer (score 0):

It's coming using `:after` css in `#makeGroupButton span:after`.

I have do some changes in your css to display arrow on hover.

```css
#makeGroupButton
{
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute; 
  width: 220px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display:table;
}

#makeGroupButton:hover, #makeGroupButton:active 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
}

#makeGroupButton span 
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;
  transition: padding-right 0.5s;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0; 
}

#makeGroupButton span:after 
{
  content: '';  
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: -14px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

#makeGroupButton:hover span, #makeGroupButton:active span 
{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#makeGroupButton:hover span:after, #makeGroupButton:active span:after 
{
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: white;
  right: 10px; 
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" id="makeGroupButton">
     <span>Button</span>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the arrow check this class `#makeGroupButton:hover span:after, #makeGroupButton:active span:after` and remove the `opacity` or `right:0` in `css` and also remove `padding` in this class css `#makeGroupButton:hover span, #makeGroupButton:active span`